# Will Object.create change the prototype object for other objects in the follow example?

Tags: javascript

Suppose if I have the following code.

```
var House = {rooms: 3};
House.switchOffMains = function(){ console.log("Mains switched off"); };

var Constructor = function(){};
Constructor.prototype = House;

var house1 = new Constructor();

var House = Object.create(House);
House.switchOffMains = function() { console.log("Function has been modified"); };
```

I have tried a similar example to this in my own code and when house1.switchOffMains() is called it logs the message "Mains switched off" rather than the new message made after using Object.create on House. My question is, why does it not modify the function on house1 since its prototype is House?

Comment: Do you mean to declare `var House` twice?

Comment: What do you think `Object.create` does?

Answer (score 0):

As @danh pointed out in the comments, the issue is that you used the name `House` for two different things, resulting in the second `House.switchOffMains = …` not referring to a property of the prototype.

```js
var House = {rooms: 3};
House.switchOffMains = function(){ console.log("Mains switched off"); };

var Constructor = function(){};
Constructor.prototype = House;

var house1 = new Constructor();
var house2 = Object.create(House);

House.switchOffMains = function() { console.log("Function has been modified"); };

house1.switchOffMains();
```

Comment: If I remove the var from the second House in my original code then it prints Mains switched off. Why is that?

Comment: @IkimSS: Because you replaced it with a new object created from the prototype. Assigning to properties of the new object will affect that object, and not its prototype. This is the same as if you had created it with `new Constructor()`.